# Как центрировать float элементы по вертикали?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, центрирование

Как центрировать `float` элементы по вертикали? Использование `vertical-align: middle` не помогает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.clearfix:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.navigation {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.logo_box {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #addddd;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul > li > a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #512422;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation clearfix">
  <div class="logo_box">some logo</div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Line1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Line2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Line3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Line4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

[Ссылка на сниппет](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wjYavP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идеальный способ это сделать — это с помощью flexbox:

```css
.navigation {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo_box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #addddd;
}

ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul > li > a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #512422;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="logo_box">some logo</div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Line1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Line2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Line3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Line4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Если нет возможности использовать flexbox, то используйте `display: table` для контейнера и `display: table-cell` для дочерних элементов.

```css
.navigation {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 40px;
  display: table;
}

.logo_box,
nav {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}

.logo_box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #addddd;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}

ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul > li > a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #512422;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="logo_box">some logo</div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Line1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Line2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Line3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Line4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Все остальные способы с фиксированными высотами или отступами, использованием  `float` и абсолютного позиционирования — я считаю хаками и не рекоммендую 
использовать без веских причин.

Comment: Соглашусь, его глобальная поддержка равна 97.3%, что не является пределом

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать свойство `line-height` или `padding`

```css
.clearfix:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  
}

.navigation {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.logo_box {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #addddd;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /**/
  line-height: 100px;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  
}

ul > li > a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #512422;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation clearfix">
  <div class="logo_box">some logo</div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Line1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Line2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Line3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Line4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: А если это нужно сделать адаптивно, допустим, что синий блок изменит свою высоту?

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi, `vertical-align` не может выравнивать элементы с `float`'ом. Один из вариантов - это `line-height`.

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете это достичь с помощью `display: flex`

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: I need answer without flex using.

Comment: Здесь принято отвечать и задавать вопросы только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, в дальнейшем так и делайте.

Answer (score -1):

Подойдет такой вариант?

```css
.clearfix:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  
}

.navigation {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.logo_box {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #addddd;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  
}
nav:before{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: "";
}
ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  
}

ul > li > a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #512422;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation clearfix">
  <div class="logo_box">some logo</div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Line1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Line2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Line3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Line4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: По-моему ваш вариант нерабочий, попробуйте увеличить высоту `.logo_box` и посмотрите что выйдет.